# How to UseSpa() in ASP.NET Core only for specific URLs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to configure my ASP.NET Core application in the way that it shows SPA app only for specific URLs. Assuming that I have two tenants: Tenant1 and Tenant2 I would like to show SPA app when user requests:

https://app.example.com/Tenant1 
or
https://app.example.com/Tenant2

I tried to do it this way:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.MapWhen(context =>
{
    var uriTenantId = new Uri(context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()).Segments.FirstOrDefault(x => x != "/");
    var tenantId = context.GetTenant()?.Id;
    return uriTenantId != null && uriTenantId == tenantId;
}, builder =>
{
    builder.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
});
```

It works it the way that for Tenant1 and Tenant2 SPA is displayed but requests for static files returns 404. Any suggestions how to configure it correctly?

Comment: You can handle this inside of the Angular (SPA) itself!